# CMU Sphinx 5prealpha (Voice recognition system) installation

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4, pocketsphinx

I wanted to try sphinx's latest version, but didn't figure out how to install it.

With the 4th version it was quite simple, I used the demo, like **Hello World** and attached the libraries (`jsapi`, `sphinx4`,`TDIFITS`, `WSJ`) to the project, as shown in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeqtLrcOogs&list=PLh5G3y7ncCcWcR_Xgv_lSAvk-3wV7p3TH&index=13

I have downloaded the program by this link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5prealpha/

There are some demos, but no libraries. Should I use the libs from the previous version?
Maybe there are any step by step tutorials on the installation of it for the noob like me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below link before starting with Sphinx4-5prealpha

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Sphinx4 uses Maven build system. Simply type ***'mvn install'*** in the top folder, it will compile and install everything including dependencies.

```
cd sphinx4-5prealpha
mvn install
```

You will see built *libs/jars* under target directory of *sphinx-core, sphinx-data* and *sphinx-samples*.

Comment: Sphinx4 uses Maven build system. Simply type 'mvn install' in the top folder, it will compile and install everything including dependencies.

Comment: What is not understood to you ?